# MATLAB: Increase code efficiency in logic statements (Metropolis method)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, logic, logical-operators

I have a code which is designed to simulate the motion of an ideal gas in a box. It is based on the metropolis method in a Monte Carlo simulation. However, I used a series of logic statements (mostly ifs) to define boundary conditions when finding adjacent particles to a randomly selected particle. The algorithm denotes a 1 for any adjacent particle inside a 1x4 matrix, and a 0 for an adjacent spot with no particle. I need the algorithm to automatically set any adjacent points outside the box to 0 for any particle on the edge of the box. Is there a way to reduce these logic statements and still get the same results? The code is below.

```
% define constants
beta = .01; %Inverse temperature
N=2000; %Duration of simulation
eps = -7;
mu=9;


for j=1:N
    a=randi(L);
    b=randi(L);
    c=randi(L);
    d=randi(L);
    % Calculate energy at positions
    if lattice(a,b)==1 && lattice(c,d)==0
        %If distribution (according to energy) suggests move,
              lattice(a,b)=0;
            lattice(c,d)=1;

         %Energy at random site/position
       E = n*(mu-eps)
            if (a~=1&& a~=L &&b~=1 && b~=L)
               adjacent= [lattice(a-1,b) lattice(a+1,b) lattice(a,b+1) lattice(a,b-1) 1];
            else if (a==1 && b==1)
                    adjacent= [0 lattice(a+1,b) lattice(a,b+1) 0 1];
                else if (a==L && b==L)
                        adjacent= [lattice(a-1,b) 0 0 lattice(a,b-1) 1];
                    else if(a==1&&b==L)
                            adjacent= [0 lattice(a+1,b) 0 lattice(a,b-1) 1];
                        else if (a==L &&b==1)
                                adjacent= [lattice(a-1,b) 0 lattice(a,b+1) 0 1];
                            else if (a==1 && b~=L && b~=1)
                                    adjacent= [0 lattice(a+1,b) lattice(a,b+1) lattice(a,b-1) 1];
                                 else if (a==L && b~=L && b~=1)
                                        adjacent= [lattice(a-1,b) 0 lattice(a,b+1) lattice(a,b-1) 1];
                                     else if (b==1&&a~=L&&a~=1)
                                             adjacent= [lattice(a-1,b) lattice(a+1,b) lattice(a,b+1) 0 1];
                                         else if (b==L&&a~=L&&a~=1)
                                              adjacent= [lattice(a-1,b) lattice(a+1,b) 0 lattice(a,b-1) 1];  
                                             end
                                         end
                                     end
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end


            E1 = mu*sum(adjacent) + eps*sum(sum(adjacent.*adjacent)); 
            %This calculates the energy of the particle at its current
            %position

            if (c~=1&& c~=L &&d~=1 && d~=L)
               adjacent1= [lattice(c-1,d) lattice(c+1,d) lattice(c,d+1) lattice(c,d-1) 1];
            else if (c==1 && d==1)
                    adjacent1= [0 lattice(c+1,d) lattice(c,d+1) 0 1];
                else if (c==L && d==L)
                        adjacent1= [lattice(c-1,d) 0 0 lattice(c,d-1) 1];
                    else if(c==1&&d==L)
                            adjacent1= [0 lattice(c+1,d) 0 lattice(c,d-1) 1];
                        else if (c==L &&d==1)
                                adjacent1= [lattice(c-1,d) 0 lattice(c,d+1) 0 1];
                            else if (c==1 && d~=L && d~=1)
                                    adjacent1= [0 lattice(c+1,d) lattice(c,d+1) lattice(c,d-1) 1];
                                 else if (c==L && d~=L && d~=1)
                                        adjacent1= [lattice(c-1,d) 0 lattice(c,d+1) lattice(c,d-1) 1];
                                     else if (d==1&&c~=L&&c~=1)
                                             adjacent1= [lattice(c-1,d) lattice(c+1,d) lattice(c,d+1) 0 1];
                                         else if (d==L&&c~=L&&c~=1)
                                              adjacent1= [lattice(c-1,d) lattice(c+1,d) 0 lattice(c,d-1) 1];  
                                             end
                                         end
                                     end
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end


            E2 = mu*sum(adjacent) + eps*sum(sum(adjacent1.*adjacent1)); 
            %Calculates the energy at randomly chosen position.

            dE = E2-E1; %Change in energy of the particle as it goes from the two locations.

            if rand<exp(-beta*dE)
                lattice(a,b)=0;
                lattice(c,d)=1;
            end



    end
 time(:,:,j)=lattice;


end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do away with all those `if else` statements. In effect you are only evaluating four logical expressions and selecting indices based on that. You can use the following

```
ab = [a-1, b; a+1, b; a, b+1; a, b-1];
abIn = [a ~= 1; a ~= L; b ~= L; b ~= 1];
adjacent = zeros(1, 5);
adjacent(abIn) = lattice(sub2ind([L, L], ab(abIn, 1), ab(abIn, 2)));
adjacent(5) = 1;
```

instead of the first set of `if else` statements, and make the name changes for the second set as well. The idea here is to only get the values of `lattice` where they are inside the borders. The four logical expressions are here used for [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) in the fourth line.